# Translate a word using an online dictionary

Tags: php, dictionary, translate

I browsed a bit already but I didn't find something that'd help me.

I want to find a way to translate a word (maybe even a phrase) with the help of an already existing dictionary.

Example:

`$translated = function("House", "de"); // tells function to translate into German`

`echo $translated; // Haus (German translation)`

I could download a dictionary and put it into my database but maybe there exist classes already that use online dictionaries? This way I'd maybe be able to translated simple phrases and use different languages!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: translate (v. en) : traduire, concrétiser, translater, transformer, convertir, effectuer une translation....   Universal laws are for lackeys, context is for kings (~~ cap. Lorca)

Comment: You could use the [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) function from PHP or better the [Symfony Translation](https://github.com/symfony/translation) component.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as soon as possible!

Answer (score 0):

Natively, PHP doesn't do that, but you could create your own function if you want to use dictionaries.

```
    function translate($word, $locale){
     // do your translation stuff here.
     // maybe you want to read a file that has the same name as $locale
     // maybe you have your dictionary stored in a database, query and return
    }

translate('House', 'de');
```

Dictionary translations are difficult as a word may translate multiple ways in another language.

Google translate apis are good to use.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do that, PHP does not provide a native method to translate text. You will need to use an external dependency to achieve it. For example:

- https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx

Comment: PHP provides the [gettext()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) function alias `__()`.

Comment: So what? He wants an "already existing dictionary", and that doesn't exist. Even with gettext or not.

Comment: He said "I could download a dictionary and put it into my database" and you said: "PHP does not provide a native method to translate text".

Comment: Wooop! That's true, that phrase is totally wrong :P